# white spaces - slack (webhook)

Tags: slack-api, slack

It looks like there is no option post a message containing a table on to slack. I am trying to build a table using text formatting. In the below example the text isn't aligned because first row has text ROW1 and second row has text ROW. Is there a way to add a white space after ROW in order to align this text?

> {"text" : "ROW1\t\t\t\tCOL1\nROW\t\t\t\tCOL2"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can use Slack's [message builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting/builder) to test the rendering of your messages.

This being said, while I dont think you can simply "push" spaces to the right, you could use the pipe symbol [like this](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22ROW1%7C%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5CtCOL1%5CnROW%20%20%20%7C%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5CtCOL2%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%22And%20here%27s%20an%20attachment!%22%7D%5D%7D) :

```
"text": "ROW1|\t\t\t\tCOL1\nROW   |\t\t\t\tCOL2"
```

Another possibility, with minor changes, is to use attachements with fields [like this](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22ROW1%7C%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5CtCOL1%5CnROW%20%20%20%7C%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5CtCOL2%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22fields%22%3A%5B%7B%22title%22%3A%22Col1%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22text1%22%2C%22short%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%22title%22%3A%22Col2%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22text2%22%2C%22short%22%3Atrue%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D)

```
"attachments": [
        {
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "Col1",
                    "value": "text1",
                    "short": true
                },
                {
                    "title": "Col2",
                    "value": "text2",
                    "short": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```